# How do you set what mongo server to write to in a Meteor app?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a Meteor application that I would like to deploy to a highly available MongoDB environment. How would I set the Meteor app to write to the MongoDB master and perform reads from the rest of the cluster? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. Meteor probably can only with one main Mongo database. It's going to be hard on you anyway to sync data between the separate Mongodb clusters. Why don't you just use a replica set so you have the backup and high availability without going out of Meteor land.